# Finding the quickest way with the least changes haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, tuples

A function,journey, that takes the name of the city where a journey is to start and the name of the city where it is to end, and returns a journey that makes the least number of changes. For example, considering Bangkok Airways only,

```
   journey "Singapore" "Singapore"
   and returns[ ]
  journey "Singapore" "Bangkok"
   and returns [ ("Singapore", "Bangkok Airways", "Bangkok") ]
  journey "Singapore" "New Delhi"
   and returns [ ("Singapore", "Bangkok Airways", "New Delhi") ]
```

In a larger network,

```
  journey "Singapore" "France"
    ====> [ ("Singapore", "Bangkok Airways", "Greece") ,("Greece", "Lufthansa", "France")]
```

this is what i have so far

```
city :: String -> (String,String,String)
city  "Singapore" =("Singapore","Bangkok Airways", "Bangkok")
city  "Bangkok" =("Bangkok","Bangkok Airways", "Bago")
city  "Bago" = ("Bago", "Bangkok Airways", "Yangon")
city  "Yangon" =("Yangon", "Bangkok Airways", "New Delhi")
city  "New Delhi" = ("New Delhi", "Bangkok Airways", "Kiev")
```

this will return the journey, however, that doesnt mean it is the shortest.
also the definition of city it needs a little more polishing as i don't think it is efficient.

Comment: It would definitely be more efficient and easier for the compiler to help you if you made your cities and airlines into two data types: `data Place = France | Greece | Singapore | Bangkok | Bago | Yangon | NewDelhi deriving (Eq, Show)` and `data Airline = Lufthansa | BangkokAirways deriving (Eq, Show`.  Then you can define `city :: Place -> (Place, Airline, Place)`, and the compiler can warn you (with `-Wall`) when you miss a pattern match.

Comment: What you want is a shortest path algorithm, ie Dijkstra's algorithm. There are graph libraries that will do this, but if you want to write it yourself you should probably start by implemented a graph datatype.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the technique called "tying the knot". With this technique graphs are represented as infinite trees:

```
data Rose  a = Rose a [Rose a]
data Graph a = Graph [(a, Rose a)]
```

The main function is quite simple:

```
lookupRose :: Eq a => a -> Graph a -> Rose a
lookupRose i (Graph rs) = fromJust $ lookup i rs

path :: Eq a => a -> a -> Graph a -> [a]
path orig dest gr = path' (lookupRose orig gr) where
    path' (Rose p ps)
        | p == dest = [p]
        | otherwise = p : foldr1 shortest (map path' ps)
```

I'm assuming, that there are no nodes without neighbors in a graph. So there are two cases:

- If you are in the destination already, then put the destination in a list.
- Otherwise search for the shortest path to the destination and prepend current node to it.

Note, that there is no cycle detection, but it's easy to add it.

The `shortest` function is totally graph-unrelated, it just receives two lists and returns the shortest:

```
shortest :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
shortest xs ys = snd $ shortest' xs ys where
    shortest'    []     ys  = (True,  [])
    shortest'    xs     []  = (False, [])
    shortest' (x:xs) (y:ys) = case shortest' xs ys of
        ~(b, zs) -> (b, (if b then x else y):zs)
```

We need a function, that constructs a graph from a list:

```
fromList :: Eq a => [(a, [a])] -> Graph a
fromList xs = graph where
    graph         = Graph $ map irose xs
    irose (i, is) = (i, Rose i $ map (\i -> lookupRose i graph) is)
```

And that's all. An example: http://ideone.com/9le557

**EDIT**

The implementation of the `shortest` function is lazy, so `shortest xs ys` produces a list in the form `z1 : z2 : ...` even if `xs` and `ys` are infinite. So `length $ take 10 $ shortest [1..] [2..]` returns `10`, for example.

Let's say `shortest` would be defined like this:

```
shortest :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
shortest xs ys = either id id $ shortest' xs ys where
    shortest'    []     ys  = Left  []
    shortest'    xs     []  = Right []
    shortest' (x:xs) (y:ys) = either (Left . (x:)) (Right . (y:)) $ shortest' xs ys
```

Then this expression

```
take 5 $ shortest [1..10] [2..]
```

reduces to `[1,2,3,4,5]`. But

```
take 5 $ shortest [1..10] (shortest [1..] [2..])
```

causes stack overflow. This is because `shortest` requires both lists to be in weak head normal form (whnf) (i.e. either `[]` or `x:xs` for some `x` and `xs`), but

```
shortest [1..] [2..]
```

reduces to

```
either (Left . (1:)) (Right . (2:)) $ ...
```

which is not in whnf. And the expression is forced further:

```
either (Left . (1:)) (Right . (2:)) $ either (Left . (2:)) (Right . (3:)) $ ...
```

and so on up to stack overflow.

But

```
foldr1 shortest (map path' ps)
```

reduces to

```
shortest (path' p1) (shortest (path' p2) (path' p3))
```

if `ps = [p1, p2, p3]`. So the `shortest` function must be lazy, since `path' p2` and `path' p3` can be infinite in a graph with cycles.

Comment: But, how is this going to work with Strings? as this only works with Char and Int

Comment: The `shortest` function is quite subtle. It is surely not the most common implementation of "returning the shortest list", since it carefully generates thunks so that the tying-the-knot process works.

Comment: @chi, why not? `shortest` is lazy, but not exotic. For example this `length $ take 10 $ shortest [1..] [2..]` prints `10`. It wouldn't, if the implementation was less careful.

Comment: My (badly expressed) point was that your comment "just receives two lists and returns the shortest" does not state that the implementation is also lazy, which is crucial for the whole approach to work. Perhaps that point should be expanded a bit.